# Web hosting - one public IP - Multiple webservers internally

Tags: apache-2.4, ip, web-hosting

Our current setup is multiple public IP's pointing to multiple Apache web servers internally (virtual).

Our new internet service will give us less public IP's so I would like to have one Public IP that forwards the web traffic to multiple internal IP's.

After doing research, I see many people with one webserver internally, but we have several.  What would be the best method of routing this traffic?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your question is a bit generic. You could probably use name based virtual hosts since that solves the issue of  not having a 1 to 1 mapping IP to host name, but the exact solution will require more info, If you public IP attached to a web server, load balancer or? How are the request then mapped to the internal servers, HTTP proxy or something else?

Comment: Something like haproxy will handle that well enough, for both http and https (with a recent version). Of course you should make sure they also gave you IPv6.